# How to extract a number from a span tag using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've cut out the tag but could anyone help me how to take number out of the tag below?

```
<span class="comments">7</span>
```

how to take 7 out of it?

```
print(tag.get('[0-9].+)', None))
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: `print(tag.text)` ? Or `soup.select_one('.comments').text` to select the tag first

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
 span = "<span class='comments'>7983</span>"
```

```
import re
number = re.findall(r"[0-9]+",span)
print(number[0])
```

Output :

```
'7983'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using SimplifiedDoc :)

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '''
<span class="comments">7</span>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.span.text)
```

Result:

```
7
```

Comment: Could you please give me the resource where can I study about Simplified Doc

Comment: @KOMARAPURIVENKATASUBHASH Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples